# About a countably additive vectorial measure

Tags: measure-theory

I need a hand with this exercise.

We consider the space $([0,1],\cal{B},\mu)$, where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. 
Let $1\leq p< \infty$. We define $F:[0,1]\to \ell^p$ as

$${F}(x):=\sum_{i=1}^{m}x^ie_i,$$

where $e_i$ is the standard basis for $\ell^p$, and $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

I have to prove that the function $A\in\cal{B} \overset{\nu}{\longrightarrow}\int_{A}F(x)\;d\mu(x)$ is a vectorial measure, and also countably additive.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: I'm unclear on the definition of $F$. Given $x \in [0,1]$, what is $x^i$? What is $m$?

Comment: $m$ is a natural number, fixed. And with $x^i$ I mean $x$ raised to the $i$-th power.

Comment: Can you give me some hints about the question?

Comment: I can try to help. The range of the function lies in the span of the vectors $\{e_1,\ldots,e_m\}$ so the range of $F$ is (isomorphic to) $\mathbb R^m$. I'm not sure why $\ell_p$ is used.

Comment: Your observation would give us that $\nu$ is a vectorial measure, I think. And how do we deal with the countably additive part?